# Sending and Receiving Responses to APDU Commands using Proximity Device

Tags: .net, nfc, proximity, smartcard-reader

I am using a Sony FeliCa RC-S380, and I want to send some APDU commands to an Android device in Card Emulation Mode (HCE) while the reader is in Reader/Writer mode. From what it looks like, I can use the  Windows Proximity library to handle communication with this reader, but I can't seem to find a way to put the reader into Reader/Writer mode to be able to send the APDU commands and receive responses.

The ProximityDevice class a function for sending a message called PublishBinaryMessage, which looks most like what I would want to use to send the command, however there is only a callback for when the message has been published and no way to get the response. There is a function that allows the reader to subscribe to messages being send to it (SubscribeForMessage), but I don't believe this gets the response to my commands.

I am able to do this easily with an ACR 1252U reader that I have by using the Windows SmartCards library, using the TransmitAsync function, which returns the response to my APDU commands.

Is there any way I can send APDU commands using the Proximity library? Alternatively, is there a way that I can utilize the SmartCards library to handle communication with my Sony reader?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "put the reader into Reader/Writer mode" since a reader will always be in that mode provided its drivers are installed.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to use Sony's SDKs available [here](https://www.sony.net/Products/felica/business/products/ICS-D004.html#Lineup)
Be sure not to confuse with Windows Software Components that are meant to support in-built NFC readers on PC/Laptops. The Sony Reader you are connecting is through USB and therefore isn't in-built

Comment: I also have a Dell Latitude E7450 which has a built in NFC reader that can be used as a Proximity Device. The focus is less on what device is being used, but rather if it is possible to use the Proximity library to send APDU commands to an NFC tag/emulated tag. I could use the Sony SDK, but in my situation I do not want to restrict it to just external Sony NFC readers, but support any reader that can act as a Proximity Device.